# What component(s) of the Google Maps API is used to generate maps plotting many addresses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to create a map with very similar functionality to the one found on the right side of this page: https://spacelist.ca/search

- Plot the addresses from database of geocoded address components
- When zoomed out, it shows the number of addresses in a vicinity as a clickable number
- Clicking on a number zooms in, and the numbers split up into smaller jurisdictions
- The side panel lists the cities/neighborhoods/campuses/addresses that are visible within the edges of the map
- Clicking on a pin shows information about that address on the side panel
- Selecting something on the side panel will show to corresponding area or pin on the map

I'm using Django for the backend.

I opened their `/application.c720f8945a.js` and scrolling horizontally in VS caused a slideshow. Even if it is the correct place to look, there is too much stuff and I don't know what exactly I'm looking for.

I don't have any idea of how or where to start, or what search terms I should use for this kind of map. If someone could point me in the correct direction on how to get started, I would really appreciate it.

`models.py`

```
class Address(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Address_created')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='Address_owned')
    visible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    street_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    route = models.ForeignKey(Route)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True)
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lng = models.FloatField()
    rating = models.FloatField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('street_number', 'route')
```

Comment: That's a lot of requests for one question.  It is doable; just a lot.  Let's start with the data.  Show me a sample of the data you have.  Show me your database table (structure). Is it php/mySQL?  Do you have the coordinates, or do you expect Google Maps to use geocode every time (I would suggest you search once, and add the coordinates to your database)?

Comment: Updated OP with model code. It's in Python, and Django converts it to SQL. Yes, it is searching once when the user adds a new address, and the coordinates are saved as a pair of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll have to answer with php & mySQL, sorry.

Here is an example that captures most of your question, I think.  With Belgian towns.

small export:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city ( id bigint(15) NOT NULL, alpha varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, longitude decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL, latitude decimal(12,10) DEFAULT NULL, code varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, name varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, province bigint(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY region (province), KEY code (code), KEY alpha (alpha) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci; INSERT INTO city (id, alpha, longitude, latitude, code, name, province) VALUES (2753, 'vodele', 4.7319823000, 50.1700235000, '5680', 'Vodelée', 10), (2752, 'vaucelles', 4.7435856000, 50.1132065000, '5680', 'Vaucelles', 10), (2751, 'soulme', 4.7362843000, 50.1875880000, '5680', 'Soulme', 10), (2750, 'romere', 4.6751612000, 50.1349753000, '5680', 'Romerée', 10), (2749, 'niverle', 4.7009273000, 50.1176372000, '5680', 'Niverlée', 10), (2748, 'matagne-la-petite', 4.6466011000, 50.1187174000, '5680', 'Matagne-la-Petite', 10), (2747, 'matagne-la-grande', 4.6230829000, 50.1171994000, '5680', 'Matagne-la-Grande', 10), (2746, 'gochene', 4.7598303000, 50.1838389000, '5680', 'Gochenée', 10), (2745, 'gimne', 4.7141846000, 50.1322987000, '5680', 'Gimnée', 10), (2744, 'doische', 4.7451565000, 50.1354941000, '5680', 'Doische', 10), (2743, 'viroinval', 4.6059942000, 50.0714722000, '5670', 'Viroinval', 10), (2742, 'vierves-sur-viroin', 4.6342325000, 50.0803073000, '5670', 'Vierves-sur-Viroin', 10), (2741, 'treignes', 4.6692223000, 50.0928419000, '5670', 'Treignes', 10), (2740, 'olloy-sur-viroin', 4.6073551000, 50.0734406000, '5670', 'Olloy-sur-Viroin', 10), (2739, 'oignies-en-thirache', 4.6390911000, 50.0237916000, '5670', 'Oignies-en-Thiérache', 10), (2738, 'nismes', 4.5483014000, 50.0747916000, '5670', 'Nismes', 10), (2737, 'maze', 4.6962280000, 50.1013002000, '5670', 'Mazée', 10), (2736, 'le-mesnil', 4.6714057000, 50.0315066000, '5670', 'Le Mesnil', 10), (2735, 'dourbes', 4.5911852000, 50.0915244000, '5670', 'Dourbes', 10), (2734, 'presgaux', 4.4198508000, 50.0251800000, '5660', 'Presgaux', 10), (2733, 'petite-chapelle', 4.5051169000, 49.9501137000, '5660', 'Petite-Chapelle', 10), (2732, 'petigny', 4.5329342000, 50.0588019000, '5660', 'Petigny', 10), (2731, 'pesche', 4.4587268000, 50.0423745000, '5660', 'Pesche', 10), (2730, 'mariembourg', 4.5221759000, 50.0949510000, '5660', 'Mariembourg', 10), (2729, 'gonrieux', 4.4262188000, 50.0360473000, '5660', 'Gonrieux', 10), (2728, 'frasnes-namur', 4.5089143000, 50.0767425000, '5660', 'Frasnes, Namur', 10), (2727, 'dailly', 4.4357088000, 50.0574819000, '5660', 'Dailly', 10), (2726, 'cul-des-sarts', 4.4546930000, 49.9620803000, '5660', 'Cul-des-Sarts', 10), (2725, 'couvin', 4.4971552000, 50.0516936000, '5660', 'Couvin', 10), (2724, 'brly-de-pesche', 4.4607012000, 50.0009904000, '5660', 'Brûly-de-Pesche', 10), (2723, 'brly', 4.5276734000, 49.9700584000, '5660', 'Brûly', 10), (2722, 'boussu-en-fagne', 4.4718043000, 50.0762654000, '5660', 'Boussu-en-Fagne', 10), (2721, 'aublain', 4.4090755000, 50.0675767000, '5660', 'Aublain', 10), (2720, 'thy-le-chteau', 4.4259158000, 50.2823570000, '5651', 'Thy-le-Château', 10), (2719, 'tarcienne', 4.4978154000, 50.3121148000, '5651', 'Tarcienne', 10), (2718, 'somze', 4.4831638000, 50.2950667000, '5651', 'Somzée', 10), (2717, 'rogne', 4.3890376000, 50.2696666000, '5651', 'Rognée', 10), (2716, 'laneffe', 4.4945456000, 50.2776590000, '5651', 'Laneffe', 10), (2715, 'gourdinne', 4.4562301000, 50.2901206000, '5651', 'Gourdinne', 10), (2714, 'berze', 4.3991598000, 50.2906721000, '5651', 'Berzée', 10), (2713, 'yves-gomeze', 4.4942942000, 50.2394220000, '5650', 'Yves-Gomezée', 10), (2712, 'walcourt', 4.4316899000, 50.2517267000, '5650', 'Walcourt', 10), (2711, 'vogene', 4.4523807000, 50.2388380000, '5650', 'Vogenée', 10), (2710, 'pry', 4.4292602000, 50.2702052000, '5650', 'Pry', 10), (2709, 'fraire', 4.5075507000, 50.2612928000, '5650', 'Fraire', 10), (2708, 'fontenelle', 4.3820441000, 50.2480932000, '5650', 'Fontenelle', 10), (2707, 'clermont-namur', 4.3166534000, 50.2602509000, '5650', 'Clermont, Namur', 10), (2706, 'chastrs', 4.4594299000, 50.2649875000, '5650', 'Chastrès', 10), (2705, 'castillon', 4.3535680000, 50.2469600000, '5650', 'Castillon', 10), (2704, 'stave', 4.6595389000, 50.2823372000, '5646', 'Stave', 10), (2703, 'ermeton-sur-biert', 4.7220269000, 50.2886049000, '5644', 'Ermeton-sur-Biert', 10), (2702, 'furnaux', 4.7035401000, 50.3074423000, '5641', 'Furnaux', 10), (2701, 'saint-grard', 4.7402044000, 50.3459587000, '5640', 'Saint-Gérard', 10), (2700, 'oret', 4.6155651000, 50.2998711000, '5640', 'Oret', 10), (2699, 'mettet', 4.6579476000, 50.3201538000, '5640', 'Mettet', 10), (2698, 'graux', 4.7188075000, 50.3256276000, '5640', 'Graux', 10), (2697, 'biesmere', 4.6800577000, 50.2972765000, '5640', 'Biesmerée', 10), (2696, 'biesme', 4.6084738000, 50.3341410000, '5640', 'Biesme', 10), (2695, 'villers-deux-eglises', 4.4827135000, 50.1895479000, '5630', 'Villers-Deux-Eglises', 10), (2694, 'soumoy', 4.4374719000, 50.1893197000, '5630', 'Soumoy', 10), (2693, 'silenrieux', 4.4101535000, 50.2247693000, '5630', 'Silenrieux', 10), (2692, 'senzeille', 4.4654506000, 50.1773954000, '5630', 'Senzeille', 10), (2691, 'daussois', 4.4538610000, 50.2215797000, '5630', 'Daussois', 10), (2690, 'cerfontaine', 4.4123064000, 50.1706980000, '5630', 'Cerfontaine', 10), (2689, 'thy-le-bauduin', 4.5236966000, 50.2951273000, '5621', 'Thy-le-Bauduin', 10), (2688, 'morialm', 4.5659309000, 50.2750372000, '5621', 'Morialmé', 10), (2687, 'hanzinne', 4.5431971000, 50.3100157000, '5621', 'Hanzinne', 10), (2686, 'hanzinelle', 4.5564457000, 50.2960690000, '5621', 'Hanzinelle', 10), (2685, 'saint-aubin', 4.5775596000, 50.2480443000, '5620', 'Saint-Aubin', 10), (2684, 'rose', 4.6867744000, 50.2321287000, '5620', 'Rosée', 10), (2683, 'morville', 4.7449983000, 50.2334567000, '5620', 'Morville', 10), (2682, 'hemptinne-lez-florennes', 4.5626703000, 50.2285443000, '5620', 'Hemptinne-lez-Florennes', 10), (2681, 'florennes', 4.6037449000, 50.2508165000, '5620', 'Florennes', 10), (2680, 'flavion', 4.7122250000, 50.2492740000, '5620', 'Flavion', 10), (2679, 'corenne', 4.6787666000, 50.2522483000, '5620', 'Corenne', 10);
```

bigger file: http://www.manutechnica.com/stackoverflow/city.sql

data.php

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect');
mysql_select_db('stackoverflow') or die('Could not select database');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

$query = 'SELECT id, latitude as lat, longitude as lng, name, code FROM city';
$res = mysql_query($query);

$my_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  array_push ($my_array, $row);
}

// print the result
echo json_encode($my_array);
// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($res);
// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

index.php

```
<style>
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
#display {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mc;
  var map;
  var markers = [];
  var markerData = [];
  function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, 4),  // Belgium
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Read the locations from database, with an Ajax call
    getData(function(data) {
      markerData = data;
      // infowindow
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        content: ''
      });
      for (var i in data) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng),
          title: data[i].name
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          //first see which marker was clicked upon
          var index = markers.indexOf(this);
          var content = markerData[index].name +'<br>postal code: '+ markerData[index].code; //feel free to add tags
          infowindow.open(map, markers[index]);
          infowindow.setContent(content);
        });
      }

      // now cluster the markers
      var mcOptions = {}; //{gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
      mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = '';
        var newContent = '';
        for (var i in markers) {
          if (markerIsInSight(markers[i])) {
            newContent += '<li onclick="zoomTo(' + i + ')">' + markerData[i].name +' - postal code: '+ markerData[i].code +'</li>';
          }
        }
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = newContent;
      });
    });

    function markerIsInSight(marker) {
      // Let's consider a rectangle, we have map boundaries.  
      // Notice, for big countries like Canada (especially when they're close to a pole), a trapezium would be better; the map shows more difference of longitude in the north than in the south, due to the curvature of earth.
      return ( // returns true or false
        marker.getPosition().lat() <= map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat()  &&
        marker.getPosition().lat() >= map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat()  &&
        marker.getPosition().lng() <= map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng()  &&
        marker.getPosition().lng() >= map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()  
      );  
    }
  }

  // Read the locations from database, with an Ajax call
  // callback is a function that will be executed when Ajax returns with data from the server
  function getData(callback) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          callback(data);
        }
      });
  }

  function zoomTo(index) {
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(markers[index].getPosition());
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
<ul id="display"></ul>
```

data.php produces data like this:

```
[{"id":"1032","lat":"51.1014829000","lng":"2.8909046000","name":"Leke","code":"8600"},{"id":"1031","lat":"51.0325201000","lng":"2.7683533000","name":"Lampernisse","code":"8600"},{"id":"1030","lat":"51.0814378000","lng":"2.8821894000","name":"Keiem","code":"8600"},{"id":"1029","lat":"51.0364146000","lng":"2.8367637000","name":"Kaaskerke","code":"8600"},{"id":"1028","lat":"51.0294638000","lng":"2.9021306000","name":"Esen","code":"8600"},{"id":"1027","lat":"50.7064502000","lng":"3.9865752000","name":"Driekapellen","code":"8600"},{"id":"1026","lat":"51.0317985000","lng":"2.8637681000","name":"Diksmuide","code":"8600"},{"id":"1025","lat":"51.0588750000","lng":"2.8869089000","name":"Beerst","code":"8600"}];
```

So feel free to generate data like this in any language, in any way you know about.

Comment: "Marker clusters" was the search term I was looking for! I have all the pieces of the puzzle now, and it's just a matter of time for me to implement it successfully. Your JS in `index.php` will really help guide me through this process. Thank you so much!