# Google Map with huge JSON array

Tags: json, google-maps

I want to display over than 250.000 points in Google Map, this take a lot and most of the time this crashes. Is there a faster way? Or can I display more markers when zoom in?

Here is my code:

```
function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: {lat: 52.881966667, lng: 11.74306},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the bandwidth.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
      var rssi = citymap[city].rssi;
      var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
      strokeColor: '#ff0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#ff0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.2,
      map: map,
      center: {lat:Number(citymap[city].lat), lng:Number(citymap[city].lng)},
      radius: 100*Math.sqrt(citymap[city].rssi)
      });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: There are two standard things I can think of.  First: load the data asynchronously, with an Ajax call.  Second: markerclusterer.  If this doesn't help, we should make something custom.  For example a grid structure clusterer, this is easy and fast to compute.   Do you understand what to do next?  Maybe it helps to look at my answer to another question involving many markers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33385185/what-components-of-the-google-maps-api-is-used-to-generate-maps-plotting-many/33403662#33403662

Comment: Sorry but I don't really get what to do? the PHP part is almost the same, I generated a JSON object with lat, lng and rssi (a number), what's next ? what to select more rows when I zoom in ?

Comment: If it's generated with php (from a database I presume), you can make an Ajax call where you send the map boundaries, so the server generates only the markers within that range.  That would be worth a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps.

I based this on the link I just gave you.

I did three things.

- I put a 1 second delay, before loading the data.
- When the client zooms or pans (or resizes the map), one second after the last change the data is loaded.  Only the locations within the map boundaries are retrieved from the database.
- MarkerClusterer clusters markers.  That's probably a good idea for your script.

I expect this to help when the map is zoomed in.  Zoomed out the problem is probably still there.  Let me know

sql export file: http://www.manutechnica.com/stackoverflow/city.sql

data.php

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect');
mysql_select_db('stackoverflow') or die('Could not select database');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);

// if a boundaries range is given
if ($_GET['north'] && $_GET['east'] && $_GET['south'] && $_GET['west']) {
  $query = 'SELECT id, latitude as lat, longitude as lng, name 
  FROM city
  WHERE (latitude between ' . (float) $_GET['south'] .' AND ' . (float) $_GET['north'] .')
    AND (longitude between ' . (float) $_GET['west'] .' AND ' . (float) $_GET['east'] .')
  ';
}
else {
  $query = 'SELECT id, latitude as lat, longitude as lng, name FROM city';
}
$res = mysql_query($query);

$my_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  array_push ($my_array, $row);
}

// print the result
echo json_encode($my_array);
// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($res);
// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

index.php

```
<style>
#map {
  height: 400px;
}
#display {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var mc;
  var map;
  var markers = [];
  var markerData = [];
  var t;  // timer

  function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, 4),  // Belgium
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

     // Read the locations from database, with an Ajax call
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() {
      getData(getDataCallback, true);
    }, 1000);

    function getDataCallback(data) {
      markerData = data;
      markers = [];  // remove the previous markers
      for (var i in data) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng),
          title: data[i].name
        });
        markers.push(marker);
      }

      // now cluster the markers
      var mcOptions = {}; //{gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
      mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        // we will put a timer on this.  So the data is only retreived after the client stops panning/zooming for a second
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(function() {
          getData(getDataCallback, true);
        }, 1000);
      });
    }

  }

  // Read the locations from database, with an Ajax call
  // callback is a function that will be executed when Ajax returns with data from the server
  function getData(callback, ready) {
      var data = {};
      if (ready) {
        data = {
          north: map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat,
          east: map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng,
          south: map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat,
          west: map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng
        };
      }
      $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          callback(data);
        }
      });
  }

  function zoomTo(index) {
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(markers[index].getPosition());
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
<ul id="display"></ul>
```

Comment: it didn't work, no markers at all, I dont see how you apss the JSON to the map ? You only echo it, you don't affect it to a variable !!!

Comment: surf to data.php . Do you get errors?  Also, obviously you must change the database settings.

Comment: yes, I use my own data, I even var_dumper at the end or the php file and got nothing, so obviously there is no call to the php file

Comment: ok I got a result, but after 3 zooms , there is alot of markers, thousands so my map crashs

Comment: data.php is a json response.  This means you must not echo anything else.  No var dumps, no error display, ... Only the JSON data

Comment: Can you e-mail me?  emmanueldelay@gmail.com.  See what ever else is needed; it looks like we'll need a few more tricks

Comment: I did, we can open a google chat since I dont have enough reputation to chat here. Thank you

Comment: The script works fine except it doesnt show the makers when I change the location (the view), any thing missing ?